# Move an Outlook 2010 Message to a Conversation

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there some way to move an e-mail message that Outlook 2010 has made a new conversation for into another conversation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at the moment.

Outlook 2010 recognizes your 'conversations' just beacuse of the subject of that email. So if you have people sending emails to you with the subject 'URGENT' they all will be linked together as a  conversation, even if there's nothing in common between them.

This also applies to emails with no subject.

**Edit:** I'll add that it is not possible if you still want to keep the conversation view.

Comment: Well - sometimes this does not work. I have a number of emails where the conversation value is empty, although the mail has a subject. This causes these mails (which have different subjects) to appear in one common conversation...

Answer (score 2):

So, would this work?

1. Add the "edit message" button to your Quick Access Toolbar
2. Copy the subject line from an email in the conversation thread
3. Go into the email you want to add to the conversation thread and click on the "edit message" button
4. Paste the subject line manually into the subject line of the email you want to link

This is not optimum, because it means you have to change the subject line of a message which has been sent to you.  Is there a better way of linking an email into an existing conversation thread?

Comment: Outlook 2013: I'm able to change the subject line but the conversation doesn't merge into the other Subject Title. There must be more than Subject that ties the messages together. Perhaps there's a unique conversation ID as well. Something must have changed since Outlook 2010.

Answer (score -1):

MFC Mapi allows you modify the conversation ID so that all relevant emails are included in the same converstaion.
https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/