# Outlook 2010 *No Subject* Messages in Same Conversation

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there anyway to get Outlook 2010 to *not* organize all of my **No Subject** e-mail messages  all in one conversation?

Comment: this looks pretty similar to [the question you posted yesterday](http://superuser.com/questions/148472/move-an-outlook-2010-message-to-a-conversation); would it make sense to combine them into one question?  sounds to me like you're investigating two different methods of solving one problem.

Comment: They're related, you're right... but the solution to this one may not be a solution to the second one. They're actually two different problems for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like Outlook's conversation view in 2010 but it has a couple of annoying features and this is definately one of them. There should be an easy way to tag certain subject lines (like BLANK) as one that you don't wish to organize on. But I haven't found it. Here's my work around though:

Create a folder called "Inbox common subjects." You'll want to add that folder to your favorits if like me that is where you usually look to see the folders you use. Then when a message comes through into your normal inbox that is bunching up a bunch of stuff together that doesn't belong together click on the move icon on the home ribon and choose Always move messages in this conversation. Then a dialog comes up and pick your "inbox common subjects" folder. Make sure on that folder you turn the conversation feature off. Still not a great solution because now you have to manage 2 inboxes but I think it is better than nothing.