# Outlook 2010 Advanced Conversations Options

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there anyway to expand on the conversation functionality in Outlook 2010?
For example, add emails to a conversation group etc. A simular question has been posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/148472/move-an-outlook-2010-message-to-a-conversation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly,  I think Outlook's new conversation feature is intended mainly to make it work better for users who pull in gmail accounts.  Adding that kind of functionality would break compatibility and therefore defeat the purpose of the feature.